# kill him or I kill both of you

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life

in the talmud Sanhedrin 74a it says that if someone is told: "kill him or I will kill you", then one is not allowed to kill him and must die rather than transgress the prohibition of murder.

But what if the person says: "kill him or I will kill you and him".

In that case is one allowed to kill the other person?

in the latter case, the other person is going to die either way, so perhaps you are at least saving one life and it is permitted

Comment: Do you ask about quantity - one against two, or you against him? Let's extrapolate it to 5 or 10 or a 100  - if you don't kill one we'll kill all.

Comment: @AlBerko not same. see last line

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but there's a fair amount of relevant analysis, with sources, in the accepted answer to [this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95358/can-you-kill-person-a-to-protect-yourself-from-b)

Comment: I thought we had this question already, but don't see it now

Comment: Also somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92196/472

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you may not...usually.

Let’s start with a passive case: give us someone to kill, or we’ll kill all of you.

**Tosefta Terumah 7:23:**

> סיעה של בני אדם שאמרו להם נכרים תנו לנו א' מכם ונהרגהו ואם לאו הרי אנו הורגין את כולן יהרגו כולן ואל ימסרו להם נפש אחת מישראל אבל אם ייחדוהו להם כגון שיחדו לשבע בן בכרי יתנוהו להם ואל יהרגו א"ר יהודה בד"א בזמן שהוא [מבפנים והן] מבחוץ אבל בזמן שהוא מבפנים והם מבפנים הואיל והוא נהרג והן נהרגין יתנוהו להן ואל יהרגו כולן וכן הוא אומר (שמואל ב כ) ותבא האשה אל כל העם בחכמתה וגו' אמרה להם הואיל והוא נהרג ואתם נהרגין תנוהו להם ואל תהרגו כולכם ר"ש אומר כך אמרה [להם] כל המורד במלכות [בית דוד] חייב מיתה.
>
> A group of people that non-Jews said to them, “Give us one of you and we will kill him, and if not, we will kill all of you” - let them kill all of them, and do not hand over a single Jewish life. But if they singled him out [i.e. hand that one over or we’ll kill all of you], like they singled out Sheva Ben Bichri, give him to them, and do not let them kill all of them.
>
> R’ Yehudah says: When are these words said? When he is inside and they are outside. But if he is inside and they are inside, since he will be killed and they will also be killed, give him over and do not let them all be killed. So, too, it says [regarding Sheva Ben Bichri] (Shmuel 2:20:22): “And the woman came to the people with her wisdom...” She said to them: since he will be killed and you all will also be killed, hand him over and you all not be killed.
>
> R’ Shimon says: This is what she said to them: Anyone who rebels against Malchus Beis David is liable to death.

**Yerushalmi Terumos 8:12:**

> תני סיעות בני אדם שהיו מהלכין בדרך פגעו להן גוים ואמרו תנו לנו אחד מכם ונהרוג אותו ואם לאו הרי אנו הורגים את כולכם אפי' כולן נהרגים לא ימסרו נפש אחת מישראל ייחדו להן אחד כגון שבע בן בכרי ימסרו אותו ואל ייהרגו א"ר שמעון בן לקיש והוא שיהא חייב מיתה כשבע בן בכרי ורבי יוחנן אמר אע"פ שאינו חייב מיתה כשבע בן בכרי עולא בר קושב תבעתיה מלכותא ערק ואזיל ליה ללוד גבי ריב"ל אתון ואקפון מדינתא אמרו להן אין לית אתון יהבון ליה לן אנן מחרבין מדינתא סלק גביה ריב"ל ופייסיה ויהביה לון והוה אליהו זכור לטוב יליף מתגלי עלוי ולא אתגלי וצם כמה צומין ואיתגלי עלוי אמר ליה ולמסורות אני נגלה א"ל ולא משנה עשיתי א"ל וזו משנת החסידים
>
> It was taught: A group of people who were walking on the road, and a group of non-Jews bumped into them and said, “Give us one of you and we will kill him, and if not, we’ll kill all of you.” Even if all of them will be killed, do not give over a single Jewish life. If they single him out like Sheva Ben Bichri, give him, and do not all be killed.
>
> R’ Shimon Ben Lakish said: That is when he is liable to death, like Sheva Ben Bichri.
>
> R’ Yochanan said: Even if he’s not liable to death like Sheva Ben Bichri.
>
> Ula bar Koshav was demanded by the king. He fled and went to Lud, by R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi. [The soldiers] came and surrounded the province. They said to [the people of the city], “If you don’t bring him to us, we will destroy the entire province.” R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi left [Ulla], appeased him, and brought him to them.
>
> Eliyahu, may he be remembered for the good, would regularly appear to [R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi]. He didn’t appear to him. [R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi] fasted many fasts, and Eliyahu appeared to him. [When asked why he didn’t appear, Eliyahu] said to him, “Would I appear to informers?” [R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi] said to him, “Wasn’t I fulfilling a teaching [i.e. the Tosefta]?” [Eliyahu] said to him, “Is that the teaching for pious ones?!”

**Rambam, Hilchos Yesodei HaTorah 5:5:**

> וְכֵן אִם אָמְרוּ לָהֶם עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים תְּנוּ לָנוּ אֶחָד מִכֶּם וְנַהַרְגֶּנּוּ וְאִם לָאו נַהֲרֹג כֻּלְּכֶם. יֵהָרְגוּ כֻּלָּם וְאַל יִמְסְרוּ לָהֶם נֶפֶשׁ אַחַת מִיִּשְׂרָאֵל. וְאִם יִחֲדוּהוּ לָהֶם וְאָמְרוּ תְּנוּ לָנוּ פְּלוֹנִי אוֹ נַהֲרֹג אֶת כֻּלְּכֶם. אִם הָיָה מְחֻיָּב מִיתָה כְּשֶׁבַע בֶּן בִּכְרִי יִתְּנוּ אוֹתוֹ לָהֶם. וְאֵין מוֹרִין לָהֶם כֵּן לְכַתְּחִלָּה. וְאִם אֵינוֹ חַיָּב מִיתָה יֵהָרְגוּ כֻּלָּן וְאַל יִמְסְרוּ לָהֶם נֶפֶשׁ אַחַת מִיִּשְׂרָאֵל:
>
> Likewise, if the idolaters say to them, “Give is one of you that we may kill him, and if not, we’ll kill all of you,” let them kill al of them, and not hand over a single Jewish life. But if they single him out, and they say, “Give us so-and-so, or we’ll kill all of you,” if he is liable to the death penalty like Sheva Ben Bichri, give him to them, but we don’t rule to them like this initially. If he is not liable to death, let them kill all of them, and do not hand over a single Jewish life.

**Kesef Mishnah ad. loc.:**

> ופסק רבינו כר''ל אף על גב דמן הסתם לא קיי''ל כוותיה לגבי דר' יוחנן משום דהוי ספק נפשות ולהחמיר דלא ימסרוהו בידים ביד העובדי כוכבים ועוד דמתניתא מסייעא ליה דקתני כשבע בן בכרי משמע כשחייב מיתה כמותו דוקא ומקרא איכא למידק הכי שאל''כ למה ליה ליואב למימר נשא יד במלך בדוד כלומר והרי הוא חייב מיתה משמע דאי לאו הכי לא היו רשאים למוסרו לו וסובר רבינו דההוא בר נש דריב''ל היה חייב מיתה כשבע בן בכרי ואפ''ה לא איתגלי ליה אליהו מפני שמסרו וא''ל וזו משנת חסידים היא אלמא דלכתחילה אין מורים כן:
>
> The Rambam rules like Reish Lakish, even though normally we don’t hold like him against R’ Yochanan, because it’s a doubt regarding life-and-death, for which we’re stringent not to actively hand him over to idolaters. Further, the teaching implies like him, since it teaches “like Sheva Ben Bichri,” implying that he was liable to death, like him. Further, one can infer from the passuk, because if this is not so, then why did Yoav need to say, “He raised his hand against King David”, that is to say, that he’s liable to the death penalty? This implies that otherwise they would have been unable to hand him over. The Rambam holds that the man by R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi was liable to the death penalty like Sheva Ben Bichri, but nevertheless Eliyahu did not appear to him, since he handed him over. He said to him, “Is this the teaching for pious ones?!” - we see that initially we do not rule like this.

The Kesef Mishnah continues:

> כתב הרמ''ך אף על פי שנמצא בתוספתא כדבריו לא ידענא טעמא מאי דהא מסיק בגמרא (פסחים כ''ה) דמש''ה אמרינן בשפיכות דמים יהרג ואל יעבור דסברא הוא מאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי והכא ליכא האי סברא דהא יהרגו כלם והוא עצמו ומוטב שיהרג הוא עצמו ואל יהרגו כולם. ואני אומר שאין טענתו טענה על התוספתא דאיכא למימר דהתם שאני שיחדו לו וא''ל קטול לפלניא ומש''ה אי לאו טעמא דמאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי לא הוה אמרינן דיהרג ואל יעבור והיינו דקתני סיפא יחדוהו להם אבל ברישא שלא יחדוהו שלא אמרו אלא תנו אחד מכם ונהרוג אותו בכל אחד מהם שירצו למסור אותו איכא למימר להו מאי חזיתו שתמסרו את זה תמסרו אחד מכם ותצילו את זה דמאי חזיתו דדמא דהאיך סומק טפי דלמא דמא דהאי סומק טפי וע''פ טענה זו א''א להם למסור שום אחד מהם אבל אי קשיא על ר''ל קשיא דאמר שאע''פ שיחדוהו להם אם אינו חייב מיתה לא ימסרוהו דהא ליכא הכא סברא דמאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי שהרי הוא והם נהרגים אם לא ימסרוהו. ואפשר לומר דס''ל לר''ל שמ''ש דבש''ד סברא הוא אינו עיקר הטעם דקבלה היתה בידם דש''ד יהרג ואל יעבור אלא שנתנו טעם מסברא להיכא דשייך אבל אין ה''נ דאפילו היכא דלא שייך האי טעמא הוי דינא הכי דיהרג ואל יעבור:

In short, he quotes the Ramach, who asks why we don’t apply the general rule that murder is forbidden, based on “what do you see that his blood is redder - maybe your blood is redder.” Seemingly we don’t apply that here, as even if he is included in the group, we still kill all of them according to the Rambam and according to Reish Lakish.

The Kesef Mishnah takes issue with this argument, saying that without “what do you see,” we wouldn’t require that he be liable to the death penalty when he’s singled out to permit his being handed over. In the first case, where they don’t single anyone out, the logic is that nobody can be handed over, because who can determine who’s blood is “reddest”? The question on Reish Lakish, he says, is the case where he’s singled out but not liable to the death penalty: why don’t we say the fact that he’s singled out makes his blood “redder,” since he’s going to die anyway? Perhaps, he says, the reason that one must give up his life by murder is not the logic, but a tradition; the logic was later posed to justify the tradition, but the law still holds even when the logic does not.

I feel justified in applying all of this to your case, where he says to kill him, rather than to give him over to be killed, based on the Kesef Mishnah: the same logic of being stringent by life-and-death and therefore not actively handing him over extends to not actively killing him as well. Additionally, because the second half of the Kesef Mishnah explicitly compares this case with a standard case of murder, by attempting to apply “what do you see,” we see another proof that the two cases can be equated.

**Therefore:**

Your logic is the one posed by R’ Yehudah and R’ Yochanan, but the Halacha does not follow them. Even though he was singled out, unless he happens to be liable to the death penalty, one may not kill him, but rather allow both of them to be killed.